# 'XPath' not 'dsig-xpath:XPath'?

Tags: java, xml, sign, xpath-2.0, xades4j

How to get 'XPath' not 'dsig-xpath:XPath'  ?

```
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SigFrs">
<ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
  <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
  <s:Reference Id="signatureId" URI="">
    <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
        <dsig-xpath:XPath xmlns:dsig-xpath="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect">/Root/Element1</XPath>
        <dsig-xpath:XPath xmlns:dsig-xpath="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect">/Root/Element2</XPath>
      </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>6D+1WZjC....vGidMqCX5uCL1rw=</ds:DigestValue>
  </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
```

to get like this :

```
    <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
        <XPath xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect">/Root/Element1</XPath>
        <XPath xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect">/Root/Element2</XPath>
      </ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
```

This may look like the .jar I imported (xmlsec-2.1.0.jar) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the prefix to an empty string :

```
   ElementProxy.setDefaultPrefix("http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2", "")
```